# how to perform image enhancement over a small region of an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I would like to enhance a portion of the image. I would like to enhance the regions within rectangular region esp on the green rectangle region

Comment: What do you mean by enhance? If you have the coordinate of the rectangle, then you can apply any function only to that area, because it is considered as a matrix.

Comment: adjust the contrast .imcontrast is not working

Comment: how to get the coordinates of the rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`imcrop`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcrop.html).

```
[I2 rect] = imcrop(I)
```

This will ask you to draw a rectangle and `rect` will thus contain the coordinates of that rectangle. `I2` contains the cropped image and you can then apply any function you would like on that matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Using a function like `ginput` you can select a point on an image, and with having a width and height values of a rectangle, you can crop a rectangle from your image. Then you can use any function such as `imadjust` to enhance your cropped part.

```
a= 100;                             % height
b= 100;                             % width 
I = imread('myimage.png');          % read the image file
figure;imagesc(I);                  % plot the image
[x,y] = ginput(1);                  % select a point
I2 = I(:,:,1);                      %
Ic = imcrop(I2,[x-a/2 y-b/2 a b]);  % crop a rectangle around the selected point
J = imadjust(Ic);                   % adjust the contrast
```

If you want to be able to select a rectangle, you can use the following command:

```
imshow('myimage.png');
rect = getrect;
```

Comment: J=imadjust(Ic) is correct. But it didnt produce sufficient contrast.any suggestion for tht green rectangle?

Comment: @abcd - Try another method... like `histeq`.

Comment: once histeq is applied,i lost all connected components and segmentation result is not good